# Content Provider uri for single item vs uri to list of items

Tags: android

I have followed this article for creating a custom content provider http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/19/create-and-use-custom-content-provider/. The problem I'm facing is with the URI and URIMatcher. I know we can urimatcher to match uri for a single item vs uri for list of items. But what If i dont use any uri matching concept eg I can write

```
CONTENT_URI is "pete.android.contentprovider"
String where = BaseColumns.COLUMN_ID + "?"
getContentResolver.delete(CONTENT_URI, where, new String[]{"2"})
```

The above query will delete the 2 row from the database table. If I can do this directly by using the where clause then why should I use switch case in delete function to determine whether the uri is for single item or multiple item.

What is the standard approach. I'm totally confused with this and cannot find a proper answer on any blog or forum.

Comment: That was just a sample code :-)

Comment: I usually simply convert the id in the path (if present) into something like "id = ?" in the request. I consider it more of a shortcut

Comment: You mean Uri.withAppend? It means making lots of switch cases right? What about adding a string not a numeric value, and adding combination of both. In short lots of use cases will be hard to write and maintain...

Answer (score 4):

For 1 thing, you really want to abstract all of your data logic away from you application logic and into the contentProvider.  This is just good practice.   What if your data schema changes?

Try building your id-specific URI String by appending the ID like such:

```
Uri singleUri = ContentUri.withAppendedId(CONTENT_URI, 2);
```

Then build your query withing the specific branch of your URI Matcher switch case.

Comment: A good answer but what if I want to pass a string instead of a numeric values in the singleUri. Means again a switch case. And what if I want to pass 2 numeric values/string values means a hundreds of switch cases. How to handle that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to have separate logic for Item type and Dir type (many items)

Under item type you can directly delete item. Because you know exactly your item.
Under dir type you can use where clause for logic that you need to filter items that you need to delete.

Comment: I have seen many posts that don't even implement the getType methods in content provider. I'm currently building a content provider that can handle any type of query but that I cannot handle if there are hundreds of different uri's. So i think without using the uri the user can execute any type of sqlite query. Isn't that?

Comment: You need to have two different URLs for one resource type. More parameters handle by where clause(selection and selectionarguments). See this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#query(android.net.Uri, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String)